# Creating a Person - Setting and Changing first and last name

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am trying to build a function that creates a person by receiving at first a full name and using methods to set the first, last and full name. Afterwards it would have methods that should be able to change each part of the name.

My current code looks like this:

```
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {

  var name = firstAndLast;

  this.getFirstName = function() { 
    return name.substr(0,name.indexOf(' '));
  };

  this.getLastName = function() { 
    return name.substr(name.indexOf(' ')+1);
  };

  this.getFullName = function() {
    return name;
  };

  this.setFirstName = function() { 
    return name;
  };

  this.setLastName = function() { 
    return name;
  };

  this.setFullName = function() {
    return name;
  };

};

var bob = new Person('Bob Ross');
bob.setFullName();
```

Now I am completely stuck when it gets time to pass a new name, so that if I do something like:

bob.setFullName('George Carlin');

and then pass:

bob.getFullName();

I should get the answer 'George Carlin'.

yet this isn't happening.

Thanks as always.

Comment: `this.setFullName = function (fullName) { name = fullName; };`...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ygvquqL2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I wasn't really understanding how the values where being passed, and that instead of working on a full name I should be working on the parts.

```
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {

var firstName = firstAndLast.split(' ')[0];
var lastName = firstAndLast.split(' ')[1];

this.setFirstName = function(firstNameNew) { 
  firstName = firstNameNew;
};

this.setLastName = function(lastNameNew) { 
  lastName = lastNameNew;
};

this.setFullName = function (fullNameNew) {
  firstName = fullNameNew.split(' ')[0];
  lastName = fullNameNew.split(' ')[1]; 
};

this.getFullName = function() {
  return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
};

this.getFirstName = function() { 
return firstName;
};

this.getLastName = function() { 
return lastName;
};


};

var bob = new Person('Bob Ross');
```